Can President sign a bill passed by one Congress once a new Congress has been sworn in if the bill is delayed being presented to him (there’s a lag)?
Scenario: Congress passes a bill & adjourns. Bill gets presented to President for approval after their adjournment (because of awaiting signatures from both Houses) and right before a new Congress is sworn in. In other words……the ten days which he has to sign bill to become law overlaps into next Congress. Can he still sign it even though new Congress is seated?

This a legal quetsion, not a question about pollitics

@Starship while it shows a lack of research (I have seen the same question asked here), it is clearly a political question, as it is about how the legislative process works. The fact that it is managed through a law would make it appropiate for [law.se] too, but I think it is a way better fit here.

Some clarity is in order. 1) A bill cannot be presented to the president without the necessary signatures. 2) A bill is considered presented to the president when delivered to the White House not necessarily to the person of the president. So, Bill gets presented to President for approval after their adjournment (because of awaiting signatures from both Houses) simply cannot occur.

Seems like a valid enough question into mechanisms used to manage governments.  The lack of research criteria has no really clear guidance here and it's a neutral enough procedural question that has a clear, short answer - i.e. not inviting long form essays.  Also, IMHO, the laws/rules for govt procedures are at the intersection of politics and law, not necessarily relegated to law only.  Welcome aboard, +1.

Re. the "lack of research" cited, it is rather funny that if the answer to this question was so obvious, an initial answer stating one position completely opposed to the current +17 answer started out at +4 (probably because it sounded "obviously correct").  I for one was surprised at the current answer.

In Edwards v. United States, 286 U.S. 482 (1932), the Supreme Court was presented with this question and decided that a bill presented to the president before the end of a term of a Congress could be signed into law by the president after the end of that Congressional term.

Did the Act of March 5, 1931 (46 Stat. 2163), becomes (sic) law when it was approved by the President on March 5, 1931, after the final adjournment on March 4, 1931, of the Congress which had passed it?


There is nothing in the words of the Constitution which prohibits the President from approving bills, within the time limited for his action, because the Congress has adjourned, and the spirit and purpose of the clause in question forbid the implication of such a restriction. The provision that a bill shall not become a law if its return has been prevented by the adjournment of Congress is apposite to bills that are not signed, not to those that are signed. There is no requirement that bills that are signed should be returned. No further action is required by Congress in respect of a bill which has been presented to the President, unless he disapproves it and returns it for reconsideration as the Constitution provides.


In the instant case, the President, to whom the bill was presented, approved it within the time prescribed by the Constitution, and upon that approval it became a law. The question certified is answered in the affirmative.
It is so ordered.

The Court cited the presentment clause.

in other words: the new congress does not have to re-approve the bill before it is presented to the president for signing.
